# What does 'boo' mean in the popular gif "boo this man"?

Tags: meaning

I found a lot of people tweet about "boo this man" gif.

What does it mean?

Thanks

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boo

Comment: Please indicate what research you have done for yourself, and what specifically you are unsure about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Boo" is the opposite of applause. Making the "Booo" sound at a performance is a form of heckling. So the tweet is suggesting that someone has done something that deserves public ridicule.